# Український синонім до слова "девелопер"

Tags: іншомовні-слова

У сфері будівництва вже багато років використовується слово "Девелопер", що прийшло до нашої мови з англійської.

В інтернеті знайшлися гідні пояснення, наприклад:

> Девелопер - підприємець, що отримує свій прибуток від створення
>   об'єктів нерухомості (девелопменту), для чого він виступає в якості:
>
> автора ідеї проекту, що створювати і де;
>
> набувача земельної ділянки під забудову;
>
> організатора проектування об'єкта (ліцензованими проектантами),
>   наймача 
>          генпідрядника (з ліцензією на виконання функцій генпідрядника),    керуючих нерухомістю (при необхідності);
>
> фінансує сам або залучає у разі необхідності інвестиції.

[ЩО ТАКЕ «ДЕВЕЛОПМЕНТ» І ХТО ТАКИЙ «ДЕВЕЛОПЕР»?](http://www.svdevelopment.com/ua/info_guide/polinfo/glossary/31/244/)

Також з інтернету вдалося дізнатися, що український закон використовує для цього лиш слово "Замовник", і жодного разу "Девелопер".

> Замовник - фізична або юридична особа, яка має у власності або у
>   користуванні земельну ділянку, подала у встановленому законодавством
>   порядку заяву (клопотання) щодо її забудови для здійснення будівництва
>   або зміни (у тому числі шляхом знесення) об'єкта містобудування.

[Про архітектурну діяльність](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/687-14)

Питання в тому, чи можна дібрати синонім українського походження до слова "Девелопер", особливо враховуючи, що існує й інша сфера його використання - цифрові технології, програмування, де усталена паралельна форма - "розробник".

Answer (score 10):

Є цілком вживане слово **Забудовник**. Вікіпедія визначає його так:

> *[**Забудовник**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) — це особа, яка у встановленому законодавством порядку отримала право на використання земельної ділянки для спорудження об'єктів житлового будівництва або згідно з укладеними договорами має право розпоряджатися житловою площею у будинках, які будуються (реконструюються).*
>
> *Забудовником може виступати юридична особа, включаючи ФО-П.* […]

СУМ-11 визначає це слово так:

> [**ЗАБУДО́ВНИК**](http://sum.in.ua/s/zabudovnyk), а, чол. Той, хто будує що-небудь для себе.

СУМ-20 визначає це слово так:

> [**ЗАБУДО́ВНИК**](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=27736&page=928), а, ч. Той, хто щось споруджує, забудовує якусь територію. // Організація, яка займається спорудженням певного будівельного об'єкта на замовлення.